# Can't set property in parentViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, properties, parent-child, parent

I have a view controller, MainViewController in which I have a UIButton as an IBOutlet that is connected up in Interface Builder

In the header I have

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController;
    UIButton *leftTextButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet  UIButton *leftTextButton;
```

in the .m I have synthesised the property

```
@synthesize leftTextButton;
```

I then add a settings subview as follows

```
SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" 
                                                              bundle:nil];
[self.view.superview addSubview:settingsViewController.view];
```

Within the SettingsViewController I then try to update the title of the  UIButton *leftTextButton in the parent view

```
[ ((MainViewController*) self.parentViewController).leftTextButton setTitle:@"Ahhhhh !!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Although this doesn't crash it doesn't work - the title of the button does not change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In what method are you updating the title? If it's in the init method then it won't work, viewDidLoad would be the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parentViewController` property is `nil` unless the view controller is presented modally, or is under a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`.

Give your `SettingsViewController` a `mainViewController` property:

```
@interface SettingsViewController
...
@property (assign) MainViewController *mainViewController;
```

Set it when you create the `SettingsViewController`:

```
SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController"  bundle:nil];
settingsViewController.mainViewController = self;
```

Then you can use it to update the button title:

```
[self.mainViewController.leftTextButton setTitle:@"Ahhhhh !!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Rob, absolutely spot on. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

If you just add the view controller's view in the parent view, the view controller will have no idea of its parent view controller, thus the `parentViewController` property is `nil`. You also have to add your SettingsViewController to your MainViewController via `addChildViewController:` and then notify the SettingsViewController via `didMoveToParentViewController:` that you have created this hierarchy. Then you should be able to access the `parentViewController`.

(Note: this is for iOS 5 only, if you're still on iOS 4 see rob mayoff's reply)

Comment: TriPhoenix - not using iOS5, targeting earlier iOS to try to enable a larger user base. Many thanks for the quick response though